# how to add date to mysql error log

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Mysql error logs only have a number next to them and the time they were created, I need to format it so that it also includes the date,

how should I do it?

```
130207  2:25:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130207  2:25:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130207  2:25:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
130207  2:25:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130207  2:25:29 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130207  2:25:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
130207  2:25:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130207  2:25:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130207  2:25:30  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't 130207 the 7th of February 2013 ?

Answer (score 4):

@mimipc is correct, those first 6 characters are indeed YYMMDD.

A [change](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-9.html) was introduced beginning in MySQL 5.6.9:

> **mysqld** now writes dates to the error log in ISO (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) format. It also includes its process ID following the date.

I would not expect this to be back-ported into previous versions... but there's a patch attached to [Bug #56240](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56240) that you could probably use on earlier versions if you were *really* motivated... however, MySQL 5.6 is now officially in [General Availability status](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1904335) with MySQL 5.6.10.