# Format MySQL query log date

Tags: mysql, date

I've enabled MySQL query logging

```
general_log_file = "C:/mysql/logs/queries.log"
log-bin = "C:/mysql/logs"
general_log_file = "C:/mysql/logs/queries.log"
log-warnings = 1
general-log
```

However the date format is not conductive to quick visual interpretation:

```
160509 16:27:33 1871 Connect db@localhost on db_name
160509 16:27:36 1872 Connect db@localhost on db_name
```

How can I format the date stamp in the MySQL query log?

In example:

```
2016-05-09 16:27:33 1871 Connect db@localhost on db_name
2016-05-09 16:27:36 1872 Connect db@localhost on db_name
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? I believe this was changed from YYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD in a previous release.

Comment: Yep. 5.6.9 should have the format you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758904/how-to-add-date-to-mysql-error-log

Comment: @gotmikhail Thanks, post it as an answer and I'll accept. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL release 5.6.9 changed the log formatting from `YYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`. Looks like your option is to upgrade.

Comment: MariaDB 10.1.36 still has amateur-hour stuff like "181015 16:37:52". Goddammit.